# PHP MYSQL jQuery redirect by name result from search on click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i am trying to redirect the user after clicking the result from a search bar. i have the following code but i am getting the error Access forbidden,
i think i have this code written incorrectly, here is my current code for the said  on click event..
thanks in advance..
i have tried multiple permutations but was not successful in every try.
i really think that the problem iw in my code..

```
    var link = "somepage.php" + "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name  = 
'($name').text()";
```

the entire script for this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    if(inputVal.length){
$.get("ifyouseekaye.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
          resultDropdown.html(data);
        });
    } else{
        resultDropdown.empty();
    }
  });
$(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
$(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
$(this).parent(".result").empty();
var link = "somepage.php" + "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE name  = '($name').text()";
console.log(link);
window.location = link;
});
});
</script>
```

this is the page that feeds result to the main page.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ajax_crud");
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name LIKE ?";
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);
    $param_term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 echo "<p>" . $row["name"] . "</p>";
}
}
else{
            echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
        }
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " .             mysqli_error($link);
    }
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Please take a course/tutorial about the languages you're using. There are **many** things wrong with that single line of code you wrote.

Comment: Please post more of that code. This alone does not make much sense...

Comment: i almost forgot, i just started learning php mysql ajax and jquery/javascript just a few weeks so i think it is understandable that i can and will make mistakes, and obviously i made another one when i came her for an answer.

anyway, for the sake of some fellas who would like to help, i added the entire script which refers to my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be sent to a page after the button has been pressed, you need to start with the basics and check that your HTML is well formed.

As an example :

```
<form action="somepage.php" role="search" method="get">
  <div>
    <label for="input-search">Search the site :</label>
    <input type="search" name="input-search" id="input-search" value="">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When the user clicks on the search button, the browser will send the user and the value of "input-search" (what the user types in the input) to "somepage.php" using the GET method.

Try getting the value of "input-search" on "somepage.php" with PHP. And when it works, you can go further and add some Javascript to enhance your form. One step at a time, and always start with HTML.

Comment: i think i have to fix my php page that feeds the search resuLt to this page with the search box..